# CalibratedClassifierCV doesn't work with Pandas DataFrame for Pipeline?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I built a classification model using sklearn Pipeline. Now I want to run CalibratedClassifierCV to calibrate the probability prediction.

```
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
train = pd.read_csv('new_train.csv')
features = ['BVW_2C', 'PHIT_2C', 'SW_2C', 'VCARB_2C', 'VCLAY_2C', 'VKER_2C', 'VPYR_2C', 'VSAND_2C', 'GOLD_DTC', 'GOLD_DTS', 'GOLD_GR', 'GOLD_NPHI', 'GOLD_PEF', 'GOLD_RDEEI', 'GOLD_RHOB', 'HETI_NORM_GR']
clf_iso = CalibratedClassifierCV(model, cv=3, method='isotonic')
clf_iso.fit(train[features], train[['trouble']])
```

Pretrained model was loaded from a file, it basically composed of a scaler and a gradient boost classifier. If I print out the model, it looks like this:

```
Pipeline(steps=[('preproc',
                 ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('num',
                                                  Pipeline(steps=[('scaler',
                                                                   StandardScaler())]),
                                                  ['BVW_2C', 'PHIT_2C', 'SW_2C',
                                                   'VCARB_2C', 'VCLAY_2C',
                                                   'VKER_2C', 'VPYR_2C',
                                                   'VSAND_2C', 'GOLD_DTC',
                                                   'GOLD_DTS', 'GOLD_GR',
                                                   'GOLD_NPHI', 'GOLD_PEF',
                                                   'GOLD_RDEEI', 'GOLD_RHOB',
                                                   'HETI_NORM_GR'])])),
                ('clf',
                 LGBMClassifier(max_depth=30, n_estimators=300,
                                num_leaves=200))])
```

For some reason I got the following error while executing `clf_iso.fit(train[features], train[['trouble']])`.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/p/ressim02/analytics/AICOE/jiaod/geonet-ml/geo-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in _get_column_indices(X, key)
    424         try:
--> 425             all_columns = X.columns
    426         except AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-cfae22cb4b89> in <module>
      1 clf_iso = CalibratedClassifierCV(model, cv=3, method='isotonic')
----> 2 clf_iso.fit(train[features], train[['trouble']])
```

`train[features]` is clearly a Pandas Dataframe (confirmed by `type(train[features])`). Why does it still see it as numpy array. If I just retrain the same data again with loaded model `model.fit(train[features], train[['trouble']])`, it works without any issue. Why doesn't it work with CalibratedClassifierCV?

**EDIT**

Looks like a known issue [link](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/8710/499113383) ([github issue #8710](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8710))